# Can i create a class dynamically based on the inputs from user?

Tags: .net, class, dynamic

I've a requirement like to read an xml file and to store the values as a collection of objects. but the xml is not a predifined one, so based on the xml input I need to create the class so that I can create its instance and store it as a collection.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the c# compiler to compile text (c# text of course) into classes and output them into a dll file.

[C# Compiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, while going through msdn I've got the answer for my question.                                                      http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404245.aspx

Comment: No probs. Be sure to accept and answer to help future searchers!